# Autonauts on Debian 11: how to make it work with Proton?

Tags: steam, linux, steam-play, proton

I want to play Autonauts on Debian 11 using Steam Play compatibility tools (Proton).

How to make it work correctly using Proton? No version seems to be able to make it work.